# NullPointerException that stays at the same line no matter what

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I'm trying to code this Minecraft plugin but I keep getting a NullPointerException at onEnable() on the CompMeme class (Line 16), strangely at the same line even if I put a System.out.print() in. If the NullPointerException was not there, it would be intended that the plugin would simply load without any more messages. How do I fix this NullPointerException?

```
[21:51:15] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling CompMeme v0.1.5-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at escaperestart.sircomputer.compmeme.CompMeme.onEnable(CompMeme.java:16) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:335) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:402) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:370) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:325) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:211) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:505) [spigot-1.8.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [?:1.7.0_51
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, here's my `CompMeme` class:

```
public final class CompMeme extends JavaPlugin {

    public static CompMeme plugin;
    public String version = "0.1.6-SNAPSHOT";

    public void onEnable() {
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();

        getCommand("rofl").setExecutor(Executor.rofl);
        getCommand("facepalm").setExecutor(Executor.facepalm);
        getCommand("lol").setExecutor(Executor.lol);
        getCommand("iliketrains").setExecutor(Executor.iliketrains);
        getCommand("blamenill").setExecutor(Executor.blamenill);
        getCommand("odns").setExecutor(Executor.odns);
        getCommand("ragequit").setExecutor(Executor.ragequit);
        getCommand("rage").setExecutor(Executor.rage);
        getCommand("compmeme").setExecutor(Executor.compmemecmd);
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        saveConfig();
    }
}
```

and here's my `Executor` class:

```
public class Executor {
    public static CompMeme compmeme = CompMeme.plugin;

    public static BasicCommand rofl = new BasicCommand(compmeme, "rofl", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN, "[Rofl]");
    public static BasicCommand facepalm = new BasicCommand(compmeme, "facepalm", ChatColor.AQUA, "[Facepalm]");
    public static BasicCommand lol = new BasicCommand(compmeme, "lol", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN, "[Lol]");
    public static BasicCommand iliketrains = new BasicCommand(compmeme, "iliketrains", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE, "[Trains!]");
    public static BasicCommand blamenill = new BasicCommand(compmeme, "blamenill", ChatColor.DARK_RED, "[Blame Nill]");
    public static InputCommand odns = new InputCommand(compmeme, "odns", ChatColor.GOLD, "[ODNS]");
    public static Rage rage = new Rage(compmeme);
    public static Ragequit ragequit = new Ragequit(compmeme);
    public static CompMemeCmd compmemecmd = new CompMemeCmd(compmeme);
}
```

and here's my `plugin.yml`:

```
name: CompMeme
main: escaperestart.sircomputer.compmeme.CompMeme
version: 0.1.5-SNAPSHOT
description: Meme commands for EscapeRestart
author: SirComputer

commands:
  rofl:
   description: Makes you roll on the floor laughing.
   usage: /rofl
   permission: compmeme.rofl

  facepalm:
   description: Makes you facepalm.
   usage: /facepalm
   permission: compmeme.facepalm

   lol:
    description: Makes you laugh out loud.
    usage: /lol
    permission: compmeme.lol

   iliketrains:
    description: Show your support for trains.
    usage: /iliketrains
    permission: compmeme.lol
    aliases: trains

   blamenill:
    description: Makes you blame Nill.
    usage: /blamenill
    permission: compmeme.blamenill

   odns:
    description: One does not simply...
    usage: /odns
    permission: compmeme.odns

   ragequit:
    description: Makes you ragequit.
    usage: /ragequit
    permission: compmeme.ragequit

   rage:
    description: Activate or deactivate rage mode.
    usage: /rage [activate/deactivate]
    permission: compmeme.rage
    aliases: ragemode

   compmeme:
    description: CompMeme information command.
    usage: /compmeme <info/enable/disable>
    permission: compmeme.compmeme
    aliases: ragemode

permissions:
  compmeme.*:
    default: op
    description: Ops get ALL the commands!
    children:
     compmeme.rofl: true
     compmeme.facepalm: true
     compmeme.lol: true
     compmeme.iliketrains: true
     compmeme.blamenill: true
     compmeme.odns: true
     compmeme.ragequit: true
     compmeme.rage: true
     compmeme.compmeme: true
     compmeme.enable: true
     compmeme.disable: true
```

I'm not sure if anyone else has had this happen in a Minecraft plugin - it looks like it has happened once or twice in other things though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` is thrown when you try to run a method on an object that is `null`.

Your exception says:

```
at escaperestart.sircomputer.compmeme.CompMeme.onEnable(CompMeme.java:16) ~[?:?]
```

meaning that there is a `NullPointerException` at line 16 of `CompMeme.java`, which would be this line:

```
getCommand("rofl").setExecutor(Executor.rofl);
```

It doesn't seem to actually be `getCommand("rofl")` that's the problem, but instead your `plugin.yml`, which is not indented properly. Here's what I got when I pasted it into a [YAML to JSON parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=commands%3A%0A++rofl%3A%0A+++description%3A+Makes+you+roll+on+the+floor+laughing.%0A+++usage%3A+%2Frofl%0A+++permission%3A+compmeme.rofl%0A++%0A++facepalm%3A%0A+++description%3A+Makes+you+facepalm.%0A+++usage%3A+%2Ffacepalm%0A+++permission%3A+compmeme.facepalm%0A%0A+++lol%3A%0A++++description%3A+Makes+you+laugh+out+loud.%0A++++usage%3A+%2Flol%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.lol%0A+++%0A+++iliketrains%3A%0A++++description%3A+Show+your+support+for+trains.%0A++++usage%3A+%2Filiketrains%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.lol%0A++++aliases%3A+trains%0A++++++%0A+++blamenill%3A%0A++++description%3A+Makes+you+blame+Nill.%0A++++usage%3A+%2Fblamenill%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.blamenill%0A++++%0A+++odns%3A%0A++++description%3A+One+does+not+simply...%0A++++usage%3A+%2Fodns%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.odns%0A++++%0A+++ragequit%3A%0A++++description%3A+Makes+you+ragequit.%0A++++usage%3A+%2Fragequit%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.ragequit%0A+++%0A+++rage%3A%0A++++description%3A+Activate+or+deactivate+rage+mode.%0A++++usage%3A+%2Frage+%5Bactivate%2Fdeactivate%5D%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.rage%0A++++aliases%3A+ragemode%0A++++%0A+++compmeme%3A%0A++++description%3A+CompMeme+information+command.%0A++++usage%3A+%2Fcompmeme+%3Cinfo%2Fenable%2Fdisable%3E%0A++++permission%3A+compmeme.compmeme%0A++++aliases%3A+ragemode%0A%0Apermissions%3A%0A++compmeme.*%3A%0A++++default%3A+op%0A++++description%3A+Ops+get+ALL+the+commands!%0A++++children%3A%0A+++++compmeme.rofl%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.facepalm%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.lol%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.iliketrains%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.blamenill%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.odns%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.ragequit%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.rage%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.compmeme%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.enable%3A+true%0A+++++compmeme.disable%3A+true&type=json):

```
{
  "commands": {
    "facepalm": {
      "blamenill": {
        "usage": "/blamenill", 
        "description": "Makes you blame Nill.", 
        "permission": "compmeme.blamenill"
      }, 
      "description": "Makes you facepalm.", 
      "ragequit": {
        "usage": "/ragequit", 
        "description": "Makes you ragequit.", 
        "permission": "compmeme.ragequit"
      }, 
      "permission": "compmeme.facepalm", 
      "odns": {
        "usage": "/odns", 
        "description": "One does not simply...", 
        "permission": "compmeme.odns"
      }, 
      "rage": {
        "usage": "/rage [activate/deactivate]", 
        "permission": "compmeme.rage", 
        "description": "Activate or deactivate rage mode.", 
        "aliases": "ragemode"
      }, 
      "lol": {
        "usage": "/lol", 
        "description": "Makes you laugh out loud.", 
        "permission": "compmeme.lol"
      }, 
      "iliketrains": {
        "usage": "/iliketrains", 
        "permission": "compmeme.lol", 
        "description": "Show your support for trains.", 
        "aliases": "trains"
      }, 
      "usage": "/facepalm", 
      "compmeme": {
        "usage": "/compmeme <info/enable/disable>", 
        "permission": "compmeme.compmeme", 
        "description": "CompMeme information command.", 
        "aliases": "ragemode"
      }
    }, 
    "rofl": {
      "usage": "/rofl", 
      "description": "Makes you roll on the floor laughing.", 
      "permission": "compmeme.rofl"
    }
  }, 
  "permissions": {
    "compmeme.*": {
      "default": "op", 
      "description": "Ops get ALL the commands!", 
      "children": {
        "compmeme.odns": true, 
        "compmeme.facepalm": true, 
        "compmeme.iliketrains": true, 
        "compmeme.blamenill": true, 
        "compmeme.rofl": true, 
        "compmeme.ragequit": true, 
        "compmeme.rage": true, 
        "compmeme.compmeme": true, 
        "compmeme.disable": true, 
        "compmeme.lol": true, 
        "compmeme.enable": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the commands from `lol` to `compmeme` in the plugin.yml are indented 1 space too much. To fix this, you should change your plugin.yml to:

```
commands:
  rofl:
   description: Makes you roll on the floor laughing.
   usage: /rofl
   permission: compmeme.rofl

  facepalm:
   description: Makes you facepalm.
   usage: /facepalm
   permission: compmeme.facepalm

  lol:
   description: Makes you laugh out loud.
   usage: /lol
   permission: compmeme.lol

  iliketrains:
   description: Show your support for trains.
   usage: /iliketrains
   permission: compmeme.lol
   aliases: trains

  blamenill:
   description: Makes you blame Nill.
   usage: /blamenill
   permission: compmeme.blamenill

  odns:
   description: One does not simply...
   usage: /odns
   permission: compmeme.odns

  ragequit:
   description: Makes you ragequit.
   usage: /ragequit
   permission: compmeme.ragequit

  rage:
   description: Activate or deactivate rage mode.
   usage: /rage [activate/deactivate]
   permission: compmeme.rage
   aliases: ragemode

  compmeme:
   description: CompMeme information command.
   usage: /compmeme <info/enable/disable>
   permission: compmeme.compmeme
   aliases: ragemode

permissions:
  compmeme.*:
    default: op
    description: Ops get ALL the commands!
    children:
     compmeme.rofl: true
     compmeme.facepalm: true
     compmeme.lol: true
     compmeme.iliketrains: true
     compmeme.blamenill: true
     compmeme.odns: true
     compmeme.ragequit: true
     compmeme.rage: true
     compmeme.compmeme: true
     compmeme.enable: true
```

Which removes one space from the beginning of the commands from `lol` to `compmeme`, and also removes one space for the `usage`, `permission`, `description`, and `aliases` parts of those commands in the `plugin.yml`.

You should always paste your `plugin.yml` in a YAML parser, such as http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ to make sure that there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
at escaperestart.sircomputer.compmeme.CompMeme.onEnable(CompMeme.java:16) ~[?:?]
```

indicates.

1.) Class `escaperestart.sircomputer.compmeme.CompMeme`,

```
Method `onEnable()`,

Line 16
```

2.) Coming to Line 16 of the java file,

```
getCommand("lol").setExecutor(Executor.lol);
```

Possibility is - `getCommand("lol")` is returning null.

Please debug here, somehow issue is happening here only.

Comment: Except the process for lines 14 and 15 are exactly the same (except for the changed ChatColor and strings), so why would 16 be any different?

Comment: @WhoKnows somehow there seems to be some issue, you need to debug.